# TO SPLIT THE DATA FROM ONE ROW INTO MULTIPLE ROWS WHENEVER THE DATA HAS FIXED VALUE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables (TEST_1 and TEST_2) with the same structure.

```
CREATE TABLE MDMETL.TEST_1 
(   
EMPID       NUMBER, 
EMPDATA1    NUMBER,
EMPDATA2    NUMBER,
EMPDATA3    NUMBER,
EMPDATA4    NUMBER,
EMPDATA5    NUMBER,
EMPDATA6    NUMBER,
EMPDATA7    NUMBER,
EMPDATA8    NUMBER,
EMPDATA9    NUMBER,
EMPDATA10   NUMBER,
EMPDATA11   NUMBER,
EMPDATA12   NUMBER,
EMPDATA13   NUMBER
) ;
```

and the data in TEST_1 is:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_1 VALUES (123, 10, 50, 70, 100, 20, 65, 100, 30, 45, 75, 100, 80, 100);

SELECT * FROM TEST_1;

EMPID EMPDATA1 EMPDATA2 EMPDATA3 EMPDATA4 EMPDATA5 EMPDATA6 EMPDATA7 EMPDATA8 EMPDATA9 EMPDATA10 EMPDATA11 EMPDATA12 EMPDATA13
  123       10       50       70      100       20       65      100       30       45        75       100        80       100
```

And the data in TEST2 have to look like:

```
EMPID EMPDATA1 EMPDATA2 EMPDATA3 EMPDATA4 EMPDATA5 EMPDATA6 EMPDATA7 EMPDATA8 EMPDATA9 EMPDATA10 EMPDATA11 EMPDATA12 EMPDATA13
  123       10       50       70      100
  123       20       65      100
  123       30       45       75      100
  123       80      100
```

Whenever the fields has the value 100, then it has to split into next row.
Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Welcome to SO :) StackOverflow users are not there to do everything in your place. You should edit your question and explain what you've tried so far. It will show that you made some efforts to look for answers by yourself first : [How do I ask a good question ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

**Query**:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_2
SELECT empid,
       "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"
FROM   (
  SELECT empid,
         grp,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY empid, grp ORDER BY id ) AS id,
         empdata
  FROM   (
    SELECT empid,
           COUNT( CASE empdata WHEN 100 THEN 1 END )
             OVER ( PARTITION BY empid
                    ORDER BY id
                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING ) AS grp,
           id,
           empdata
    FROM   TEST_1
    UNPIVOT ( empdata FOR id IN (
      empdata1  AS  1, empdata2  AS  2, empdata3  AS  3, empdata4  AS  4,
      empdata5  AS  5, empdata6  AS  6, empdata7  AS  7, empdata8  AS  8,
      empdata9  AS  9, empdata10 AS 10, empdata11 AS 11, empdata12 AS 12,
      empdata13 AS 13
    ) )
  )
)
PIVOT ( MAX( empdata ) FOR id IN ( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 ) );
```

**Output**:

```
SELECT * FROM test_2;

     EMPID   EMPDATA1   EMPDATA2   EMPDATA3   EMPDATA4   EMPDATA5   EMPDATA6   EMPDATA7   EMPDATA8   EMPDATA9  EMPDATA10  EMPDATA11  EMPDATA12  EMPDATA13
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       123         10         50         70        100                                                                                                    
       123         20         65        100                                                                                                               
       123         30         45         75        100                                                                                                    
       123         80        100
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Lets say if the number of columns in TEST_1 table are unknown, then is there any dynamic process to achieve this.

Comment: give me some idea to achieve this in a dynamic way, so i can write the procedure accordingly, thank you